# Finding an average daily value

Tags: sql, average

This table contains dates and the cost of apples at different stores. Ultimately I would like the SQL to report the result '$3.5', the average cost of apples through the two days. How can I modify my query below?

```
Select Date, sum(AppleCost) from table where Date between '2018-08-21' and '2018-08-22'
and group by Date;
```

Data:

```
[Date,AppleCost]

[08-22,$5]

[08-22,$1]

[08-23,$4]
```

Comment: What is `PnL` type?

Comment: @D-Shih changed it to Apple cost to make the example simpler

Comment: why the result is 3.5 instead of 3?

Comment: 8-22 average was 3, 8-23 average was 4. Average between the 2

Comment: I write an answer you can try it @alan dennison

Answer (score 0):

Group by day, as you already did, to get the sum per day, then select the average from that result.

```
SELECT avg(pnl) pnl
       FROM (SELECT sum(totalpnl) pnl
                    FROM table
                    WHERE tradedate BETWEEN '2018-08-21'
                                            AND '2018-08-22'
                    GROUP BY tradedate) x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do twice `avg`. write subquery use where clause to get expect date. To get the `avg` by date, then do another `avg` in main query.

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
     DATE DATE,
     AppleCost INT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2018-08-22', 5);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2018-08-22', 1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2018-08-23', 4);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(dayAvg) 
FROM
    (SELECT DATE, AVG(AppleCost) dayAvg
     FROM T 
     WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2018-08-22' AND '2018-08-23'
     GROUP BY DATE) t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c2375/5/0)**:

```
| avg(dayAvg) |
|-------------|
|         3.5 |
```